How to distinguish between Left/Right trigger with WIN32 raw input?
I am using the raw input API to write a simple program for my Xbox controller. I have followed the basic setup steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input and am able to get the dara for all the buttons and all. The problem I am facing is it seems that the InputValueCap for both the trigger buttons are the same thus all i get is a ULONG that is 00000001000000000000000000000000 when right trigger is fully pressed, 00000000000000010000000000000000 when both are released and 00000001111111110000000000000000 when the left trigger is fully pressed, but this is all good when they are being used separately, but whe both are oressed together i get 00000000000000010000000000000000 and in between values when they are pressed midway. My question is how to distinguish left from right when both are being pressed?
The way i am getting these values is:
for (UINT i = 0; i < device->numValueCaps; i++)
{
    ULONG value;
    if (HidP_GetUsageValue(HidP_Input, device->pValueCaps[i].UsagePage, 0, device->pValueCaps[i].Range.UsageMin, &value, device->pPreParsedData, (PCHAR)raw->data.hid.bRawData, raw->data.hid.dwSizeHid) != HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error getting usage value\n");
        return;
    }

    gControllerState.wValues[i] = value;
}

